# Nodejs service with pkg does not open the following path with powershell

Tags: node.js, nssm, node-notifier

I have an application created with Nodejs + pkg + node-notifier + open that I create as a service with NSSM.

The problem is that the npm package 'open' when the app is as a service does not work when executing a command in powershel.

I have looked at most of the documentation and I have not found a way to find out if it returns an error.

```
C:\WindowsSystem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand <encode>
```

Comment: In case someone has the same problem. I have searched a lot and supposedly you can't run shell commands from windows services for security, even if you give them permissions. The service needs an alternative app to call and ask it to do the job, but never directly from powershell. In the end what I did was to generate a *.vbs "Dim WShell..." script that runs at windows startup.